# jQuery how to acess a function within a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to access a function within a plugin but am not sure how to.

Here is a snippet of code.  I am trying to access the find_matches function OUTSIDE of this plugin and get a return from it.

```
$.fn.variation = function () {

    $.fn.variation.find_matches = function( variations, settings ) {
        var matching = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < variations.length; i++) {
            var variation = variations[i];

            matching.push(variation);
        }

        return matching;
    }
 };
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to expose the function to external scope as a utility function then you can write it as a closure function

```
$.fn.variation = function () {

    var find_matches = function( variations, settings ) {
        var matching = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < variations.length; i++) {
            var variation = variations[i];

            matching.push(variation);
        }

        return matching;
    }


    var matches = find_matches(variations, settngs);//you can call it directly

 };
```

If you want to expose the function to external context then you can use the format used by you and you can access it using

```
var matches = $.fn.variation.find_matches(variations, settngs);
```

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear...I meant access it outside of this plugin...This plugin is already loaded on my page somewhere but I have another JS script that wants to access it without having to copy the code from it out to my script.

Comment: @Rick see my upate, you can use `$.fn.variation.find_matches(variations, settngs)`

Comment: Ahhh...thats where I went wrong...I tried var matchees = variation.find_matches( variations, settings );